# Stepper Motors that are connected to A4988 drivers shake and miss steps when MCU connected to galvanically isolated relay. What may cause this?

Tags: arduino, relay, inductor, stepper-motor, cnc

I have CNC machine that I built as a weekend project, it uses GRBL 1.1 and a custom Atmega328p board that I designed. It is based on the grbl Uno adapter plus the laser capabilities that I added. At the moment I need to turn on and off the Spindle manually. It is a 500W 110V DC motor. However I find it frustrating that I need to turn the motor off manually each time after a machining process is finished.At this point there is no connection between the board and the spindle. So I changed the GRBL skript a little bit according to the comments given  to be able to turn the Spindle_EN pin high and low with G3 and G5 commands. This works and I am able to control a Mechanical Relay with the given schematic as below. Which controls the spindle.

[image]

However after this addition the Stepper motors on the Y axis started skipping steps and shaking when the spindle is on, even when there is no load on the spindle. So there is obviously some parasitic effect caused by the addition of the relay. I am guessing some sort of parasitic inductance from the spindle current causes this, which is around 4,5A, but I dont know for sure. The reason for my thinking is beacuse this happens even stronger when the motors change direction, hence my parasitic inductance idea. Any recommendations on where to start testing and probing would be appriciated. If you have an idea on how to solve the issue without having to change the whole setup would be even better. Below is a link to the schematic of the grbl shield I based my board off of.

https://server4.eca.ir/eshop/000/DataSheet/arduino%20cnc%20shield.pdf

Comment: Try an extra 5 volt supply exclusively feeding positive to the JDVcc pin (without the jumper). Make sure the 0 volt connection is very close to T1 GND i.e. don't allow relay currents and regular 0 volts for the MCU to share any common connection other than at that one point.

Comment: Tried it, the issue consists. Although the vibrations are less intense.

Comment: OK, it's a clue.

Comment: If the relay is switching on and off but you aren't supplying power to the spindle motor does it operate correctly? If so, you're looking at the motor or its power source, rather than the relay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @Andy_aka has you on the right track, but you would need a separate, isolated supply (both ground and power) on the Arduino side.  What you most likely have is that the local ground voltage near your Arduino is experiencing large swings, enough to turn your isolator on.   Here are some troubleshooting steps:

First, disconnect the relay and short out its input.  Verify that the motor runs cleanly.  This will eliminate the possibility that there is some voltage drop occurring through your power loop through the relay.  If the symptom is still occurring, you probably have an inductive or resistive current loop through your relay contacts that is dropping your supply voltage when current demand occurs, so that the motor will miss steps.

Next, re-connect the relay and disconnect the Arduino.  Short out the LED on the optocoupler input and see if your symptom is still occurring.  If the motor runs cleanly, you know it is a ground loop problem as guessed above or a problem with the Arduino.  But if you have the symptom at this point, there is enough of a current surge in the ground line to provide a voltage to turn on T1 and energize the relay.  If this is the case, make sure your T1 ground is near the Arduino and relay power is run from the Arduino 5V supply if there is enough current.  Otherwise try to find an isolator that can handle the relay current directly without T1.

If you got this far with no symptoms, it would seem that you are getting enough current in the isolator input to turn on the LED.  This could be because of leakage in the Arduino output or from the current loop issue.  Try adding either a couple of more diodes in series with DS1 to give you some more margin, or a large capacitor on T1 base to emitter to slow down the response from intermittent current surges (or both).